# Creating Custom Field with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to add an address and telephone number using FOSUserBundle. How can I add a Custom fields, with FOSuserBundle, to have a profile that contains address and telephone number....

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)? By extending your class, it lets you add the fields and properties you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in :
 when i follow the symfony documentation:https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md                        in step a) Doctrine ORM User class
i have created a folder doctrine contains User.orm.yml:

## src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml

Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: fos_user
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

this file crush any update in your entities  and update of your database shemea .The solution is to delete this folder.

Answer (score 2):

Create an own user bundle and in the MyCompanyUserBundle.php you set

```
public function getParent(){
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
}
```

Then in your new UserBundle you create a User entity and let it extend from the base user of the FOS user bundle:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname . ' (' . $this->email . ')';
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }



}
```

**EDIT**

Set the user in the config as well:

```
fos_user:
        db_driver: orm
        firewall_name: main
        user_class: MyCompany\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: problem isn't in integration of FOSUserBundle .I integrate FOSUserBundle and the problem is when I add a new champ in entity and i  follow the symfony documentation :https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md                                             and when i put in cmd :php app/console doctrine:schema:update          The result is:nothing to apdate your database is already sync

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add custom fields but you have to create your own user model.

Read the doc, all is explained:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-3-create-your-user-class

Comment: Add your fields in your model !